# Useful C++ template metaprograms

Tags: popularity-contest, c++

C++ implements a Turing-complete functional programming language which is evaluated at compile time.

Hence, we can use a C++ compiler as an interpreter to run our metaprogram without ever generating code.  Unfortunately, `static_assert` won't allow us to emit our result at compile-time, so we do need* to generate an executable to display the result.

* we can display via a compile-time error in template instantiation, but the result is less readable.

## Challenge

Implement a useful or impressive program purely via template metaprogramming.  This is a popularity contest, so the code with the most votes wins.

Rules:

1. Your program must compile against the C++14 standard.  This means that the actual compiler you use doesn't matter to anyone else.

   `-std=c++14`
2. "External" input is passed via preprocessor definitions.

   `-Dparam=42`
3. Output is via a single `cout`/`printf` line which does no run-time calculations besides those necessary for stringifying the result, or is via a compile-time error.

   `int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        std::cout << MyMetaProgram<param>::result << std::endl;
    }`

---

## Example: Factorial

#### bang.h

```
template <unsigned long long N>
struct Bang
{
    static constexpr unsigned long long value = N * Bang<N-1>::value;
};

template <>
struct Bang<0>
{
    static constexpr unsigned long long value = 1;
};
```

#### bang.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bang.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << Bang<X>::value << std::endl;
}
```

#### execute

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -DX=6 bang.cpp -o bang && ./bang
120
```

Comment: I think "useful" and "impressive" are too subjective and broad for this challenge to be a good fit for the site.

Comment: That's why it's a popularity contest :)  I'll let the voting system decide

Comment: Popularity contests still need the task to be specific and well-defined. I suggest taking a look at the [popularity contest tag wiki](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/popularity-contest/info).